# Using bootstrap-sass-loader for webpack, it continues to to silently not write style.css file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, bootstrap-sass

I've put together a list of files that would normally be requested:

- webpack.config.js
- package.json
- bootstrap-sass.config.js
- output.txt

https://gist.github.com/robertkraig/4e1440e6048805e20312

For the life of me, I've spent atleast 2 weeks trying to figure out why this does not export.

Comment: I've looked into this a bit.. I'm going to update the existing gist, seems there may be an issue, having to use raw-loader. I found this, but only worked based on some information I found on stackoverflow. But if I load this webpack configuration into gulp via gulp-webpack integration, there is a problem with persisting via raw-loader.